# Getting incorrect predictions with a trained Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have trained a Keras model using a dataset of images to classify images into different categories. The model was trained on Google Colab using TensorFlow 2.7.0.

Here is my model code:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(256,256,3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

The dataset consists of 8 classes, and there are about 1000 images in each class. The images are preprocessed as follows:

```
IMAGE_SIZE = 256
CHANNELS = 3
BATCH_SIZE = 32

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   rotation_range=20,
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   vertical_flip=True,
                                   validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
                                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                    class_mode='categorical',
                                                    shuffle=True,
                                                    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                                         target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
                                                         batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                         class_mode='categorical',
                                                         shuffle=True,
                                                         subset='validation')
```

I have trained the model for 50 epochs and achieved an accuracy of over 90% on the validation set. However, when I try to make predictions on some new images, the model is giving incorrect predictions. It seems to be predicting the same class for every image, regardless of what the image actually contains.

Here is the code I'm using to make predictions on new images:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

img_path = "path/to/new/image.jpg"
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE))
img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
img_array /= 255.

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
predicted_class = class_names[np.argmax(predictions[0])]
confidence = round(100 * np.max(predictions[0]), 2)

print("Predicted class:", predicted_class)
print("Confidence:", confidence, "%")
```

Can anyone suggest what might be causing the issue and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance.

"I have also tried to use the predict() function in the same notebook where I trained the model, using a test image, and it gave accurate results. However, when I tried to use the same function with new images, it always returns the same class regardless of the input image. I have included the code for my model and preprocessing steps below for reference."

Comment: How do you load and save the model?

Comment: for saving the model : tf.keras.models.save_model(model,'/content/drive/MyDrive/pl/my_model.h5')               for loading the model :model_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/pl/my_model.h5' model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

Comment: Can you maybe provide the data set you are using? If not can you give us an insight into how the dataset looks like?

Comment: Plant village Dataset. The issue I was facing earlier is solved. Thanks for commenting @Fabian

Comment: Glad to hear that! Maybe you can update your question with the part that solved your problem so others can learn from it too :)